# Copying code into R?

Tags: r

This is a very basic and stupid question, but I just haven't been able to phrase it correctly into Google to get an answer.

I'm going through a book to learn R, and there are often code samples that I'd like to copy and run, but the only way I know how to do this is to copy it line by line, or put it in a text file and then use `source("text_file.txt")`.  Simply copy and pasting multiple lines into the terminal produces errors.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Copying and pasting multiple lines of code should work a-ok in RGui, RStudio, or any standard terminal. Just make sure the code doesn't have `>` or `+` at the start of lines.

Comment: What errors specifically are you getting?

Comment: The code does have `>` in front of it, but the errors weren't complaining about that.  Since my book is including them, is there a way to filter them out or make RStudio ignore them?

Comment: It looks like my errors were just being caused by the `>` in front of the code.  Is there a way to prevent this?  I can copy the code in line by line and skip the `>`, but it would be much easier to be able to filter them out or something

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is, in R GUI, select File > New script. Paste the lines of code, select them and Ctrl + R.

Or you can select any chunk of code and hit Ctrl + R to run them. This is good for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Which R are you using?

You're probably working only off the command line and don't have a script open. In RStudio, click File -> New File -> R Script (or Ctrl+Shift+N) to create a script, which you can save like a text file. Copy-paste all your code into that and click Ctrl+A (to select all lines) and Ctrl+R to run all at once.

Best,
Jan